# JavaScript jquery.ajax in success after loop nothing working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need to pass some values to other function in Javascript. I have got the values from another PHP file but I can not pass it to any other Javascript Function. Nothing is working in SUCCESS after FOR LOOP. Need Help?

```
url1 = 'http://localhost:81/Dashboard/admin/inc/dashboard.php';
$.ajax({
    url: url1,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data)
    {
        for(var i = 0; i <= 11; i++) 
        {
            Month = data[i].Month;
            Sales = data[i].Sales;
            if (i == 0) global_ij = "[" + Month + "," + Sales + "]";
            else global_ij = global_ij + "," + "[" + Month + "," + Sales + "]";
        }
        alert ("hello"); // this alert is also not working
    }
});
```

Comment: I need to use final value of global_ij variable in another function in the same javascript file.

Comment: You're not using `data` at all in your success function? What is the purpose of your ajax call otherwise?

Comment: where is `S` declared? Should it not be `Month = data[i].Month;`?

Comment: Sorry...data is there...I was trying to find some solutions...but still I cant pass value of global_ij to another function or I cant even alert it after loop.

Comment: [{"Month":"1","Year":"2015","Sales":"19746.81"},{"Month":"2","Year":"2015","Sales":"17902.26"},{"Month":"3","Year":"2015","Sales":"19223.84"},{"Month":"4","Year":"2015","Sales":"18840.88"},{"Month":"5","Year":"2015","Sales":"19889.97"},{"Month":"6","Year":"2015","Sales":"18509.85"},{"Month":"7","Year":"2015","Sales":"1886.81"},{"Month":"8","Year":"2015","Sales":"1740.34"}]

This is response from php file

Comment: Ofcourse you can pass global_ij to another function, but if you're using a naming convention of global, then you don't need to pass it via a function. Declare `var global_ij;` at the top and then you can use the variable anywhere.

Comment: Thats because ur global_ij variable has a local scope. Define this variable outside the loop and then use it.that should solve the problem.

Comment: Can you show us the code where you use `global_ij` and can you show us how it's called?

Comment: success: function(data)
        {
            for(var i = 0; i <= 11; i++) 
            {
                Month = data[i].Month;
                Sales = data[i].Sales;
                if (i == 0) global_ij = "[" + Month + "," + Sales + "]";
                else global_ij = global_ij + "," + "[" + Month + "," + Sales + "]";
            }
            alert ("hello");

This alert is also not working with simple hello here

Comment: @RaheelKhanLodhi Is that the full response from the PHP file, or does it have all `12` Months?

Comment: I am using index.php with <body data-page="dashboard"> and I have dashboard.js where i am trying to do this

Comment: @RaheelKhanLodhi, remember that the values of your variables inside the `success` handler will be unchanged outside of the function's scope in case you would want to refer them from other blocks; unless you call the functions and passing those values _in_ the handler at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response from the PHP file is:

```
[
    {"Month":"1","Year":"2015","Sales":"19746.81"},  // 1
    {"Month":"2","Year":"2015","Sale‌​s":"17902.26"},  // 2
    {"Month":"3","Year":"2015","Sales":"19223.84"},  // 3
    {"Month":"4","Year"‌​:"2015","Sales":"18840.88"},  // 4
    {"Month":"5","Year":"2015","Sales":"19889.97"},  // 5
    {"Mont‌​h":"6","Year":"2015","Sales":"18509.85"},  // 6
    {"Month":"7","Year":"2015","Sales":"1886‌​.81"},   // 7
    {"Month":"8","Year":"2015","Sales":"1740.34"}    // 8
]
```

Yet you are looping

```
for(var i = 0; i <= 11; i++)
```

So when `i >= 8`, `data[i].Month` will throw an "data[i] is undefined" error.

Simply use the `.length` property instead:

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
```

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/e9xr7tce/)

Comment: Bundle of Thanks....It was the same reason...you mentioned...obliged and Thanks again...Thanks all for supporting me :-)

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are performing an *asynchronous* AJAX operation. In other words, the assignments on variables `Month`, `Sale`, `global_ij` that you are making are *only* available in that particular `success` function's scope and NOT *outside* of it.

One workaround for you is to ***add `async: false` to your AJAX call*** which will force it out of asynchronous behavior, therefore allowing you to make the values assigned to those variables available to all the remaining block of code:

```
$.ajax({
url: url1,
async: false,
type: "POST",
dataType: "json",
success: function(data)
{
    for(var i = 0; i <= 11; i++) 
    {
        Month = data[i].Month;
        Sales = data[i].Sales;
        if (i == 0) global_ij = "[" + Month + "," + Sales + "]";
        else global_ij = global_ij + "," + "[" + Month + "," + Sales + "]";
    }
}
});
```

jQuery's AJAX calls return `promise` objects which enforce methods such as `.done()`, `.fail()`, etc.

On the other hand, you could also get a *promise* from the AJAX call (which you can pass around anywhere in your Javascript code) and when the promise gets *resolved* invoke it's `.done()` handler.

```
var promise = $.ajax({/* settings */});

/* --- */

// promise passed to some other block of code

promise.done(function(){
    //execute the block of code after the promise was resolved
});
```

[**Read more about this here**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Answer (score 1):

looks like your php is returning 8 elements and in your success method your loop iterates over 11 items, causing error.

I separated the success function and tried it with the data you posted and replaced the 11 in the loop with data.length. take a look at the following codepen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OyXzGb?editors=011

note that I added

> var Month;
>
> var Sales;

to keep those temporary variables inside the scope of the function.

You might need to check Data to see if it is a proper array, to catch errors. before this line:

> for(var i = 0; i < **data.length**; i++)

final output and something to try out:

```
var global_ij="";
function processData(data) {
    var Month;
    var Sales;
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
    {
        Month = data[i].Month;
        Sales = data[i].Sales;
        if (i == 0) global_ij = "[" + Month + "," + Sales + "]";
        else global_ij = global_ij + "," + "[" + Month + "," + Sales + "]";
        console.log(global_ij);
    }
    return global_ij;
}
```

try out this function without the ajax first:

> processData([{"Month":"1","Year":"2015","Sales":"19746.81"},
> {"Month":"2","Year":"2015","Sales":"17902.26"},{"Month":"3","Year":"2015","Sales":"19223.84"},{"Month":"4","Year":"2015","Sales":"18840.88"},{"Month":"5","Year":"2015","Sales":"19889.97"},{"Month":"6","Year":"2015","Sales":"18509.85"},{"Month":"7","Year":"2015","Sales":"1886.81"},{"Month":"8","Year":"2015","Sales":"1740.34"}]);

you might want to use `.done()`

Comment: Yes...That the right thing I have to do...Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code to declare the gloabla_ij variable outside the loop. somehting like below..

```
var global_ij='0';
url1 = 'http://localhost:81/Dashboard/admin/inc/dashboard.php';
$.ajax({
    url: url1,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data)
    {
        for(var i = 0; i <= 11; i++) 
        {
            Month = data[i].Month;
            Sales = data[i].Sales;
            if (i == 0) global_ij = "[" + Month + "," + Sales + "]";
            else global_ij = global_ij + "," + "[" + Month + "," + Sales + "]";
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you declare the var at the top of  the file, it can be used by any function within the file:

```
var global_ij; // declare variable in global scope of module/file

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:81/Dashboard/admin/inc/dashboard.php',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {

        var i, month, sales, len = data.length;

        for(i=0; i<=len; i++) {

            month = data[i].Month;
            sales = data[i].Sales;

            if (i===0) global_ij = "[" + month + "," + sales + "]";
            else global_ij = global_ij + "," + "[" + month + "," + sales + "]";
        }

        doSomething(); // can now call function after loop finished
    }
});

func doSomething() {
    // global_ij is now populated
}
```

Comment: no matter where you define your variables, the ajax calls in jQuery have a different behavior and as long as the behavior is _asynchronous_, your code inside the `success`/`fail` handlers of the ajax are in a _somewhat_ different scope, hence _not_ accessible anywhere else.

Comment: @Ahmad Baktash Hayeri - I don't understand your comment. `global_ij` is not bound to any context, so it won't be affected by any async issue. The variable will be available if declared at the top, regardless of the callback mechanism.

Comment: Not working......I have copied same.....but not running the function call at doSomething();

Comment: it should work, what's the exact problem/error you get?

Comment: As an example, can you observe what happens if you have a variable declared outside the `$.ajax`, and assign some value to it in one of it's handlers, then `console.log` the variable outside of the `$.ajax` soon after the ajax is finished. You'll have it's value unchanged from the one when it was declared.